# Triggering a lambda in private subnet using DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-dynamodb, subnet

I have a lambda into a private subnet (to make an external post https request), I need to trigger it from a dynambodb table. Then I have to put items into another table on dynamodb. If I put the lambda into the private subnet the trigger does not work, if I put it into a public subnet and invoke a lambda that is into the same vpc but into a private subnet invoking times out. How can I connect a lambda from a private to a public subnet in order to complete the task of trigger from the dynamo, post the external api and write the result on dynamo?

The flow is:

DynamoDB Stream (trigger when I write into the tableA)>POST HTTPS from Lambda into a VPC with ELASTIC IP>write results of the post into DynamoDB (tableB)

Comment: When you say that "the trigger does not work", what do you mean by trigger? What is invoking this Lambda function? Is it your code, perhaps running in a different Lambda function, or is it the DynamoDB service (because you've configured DynamoDB Streams to trigger your Lambda function).

Comment: Why do you want to put the AWS Lambda function _inside_ the VPC? DynamoDB and Lambda endpoints are on the Internet, so it needs Internet access. Does the Lambda function need to access any resources inside the VPC? What do you mean by "if I put it into a public subnet and invoke a lambda that is into the same vpc but into a private subnet invoking times out"? Please Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: I put my first lambda into the vpc to have an elastic ip: I have a post https request into my lambda. It calls an external software with a firewall (so the firewall allow my ip).

Comment: I use one of the lambda with invoke.lambda (nodejs) but I have a time out

Comment: Trigger of DynamoDB Stream goes in time out so it does not work

Comment: I think you're saying that you're running Lambda #1 in a private subnet so you can route traffic from it to the external API via NAT (with an EIP). And Lambda #1 is triggered by DynamoDB Streams, which should work fine (check CloudWatch Logs to verify that it's invoked). Lambda #1 then needs to invoke Lambda #2, which will write some data to a different DynamoDB table. Is Lambda #2 in VPC or not? If in VPC, is it in a private subnet? Does that subnet have a route to the internet or the DynamoDB service endpoint (via NAT or VPC Endpoint)?

Answer (score 0):

Task solved adding a gateway to Dynamodb using VPC endpoint